# Plot a chart depending on price and date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a problem. I have a dataframe (please see below). That contains prices and dates. I want to show the avg price of every month. How could I do this? I tried that, but I got the following error `KeyError: 'month'`. How could I plot a chart like below?

```
   listing_id       date  price  month  year
0           1 2021-09-07  79.00      9  2021
1           2 2021-08-07  80.00      8  2021
2           3 2021-06-07  90.00      6  2021
3           4 2021-06-05  20.00      6  2021
```

```py
d = {'listing_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'date': ['2021-09-07', '2021-08-07', '2021-06-07', '2021-06-05'],
     'price': ['$79.00', '$80.00', '$90.00', '$20.00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '', regex=False)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['month'], df['year'] = df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.year
print(df)

x = df['month'].unique()
y = df.groupby('date').avg()[['price']]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

```
KeyError: 'month'
```

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('month')['price'].mean().plot()`

Comment: Don't forget to convert `price` to float before plotting

Comment: It should be a bar plot not a line plot. `df.groupby('month')['price'].mean().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)`

Comment: As per @QuangHoang `df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '', regex=False).astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the price column to a numerical type so that its mean can be calculated, and then perform a groupby month on `df`.

As @Trenton pointed out, you should make a bar plot instead of a line plot.

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float')
df.groupby('month')['price'].mean().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what follows is answer to your question.
Anyway ...

1. Added some data for another year. In the question '*the avg price
   of every month'* is not enough precise  on how that should be taken in account
2. Plot a bar chart, following Trenton McKinney. But it would be more adequate to introduce 0 values for missing months.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'listing_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     'date': ['2022-09-07', '2022-08-07', 
              '2021-09-07', '2021-08-07', '2021-06-07', '2021-06-05'],
     'price': ['$79.00', '$85.00','$79.00', '$80.00', '$90.00', '$20.00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '', regex=False).astype(float)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month])['price']
 .mean()
 .plot(kind = 'bar',
       rot = 0,
       xlabel = '(year, month)',
       ylabel = 'price')
)
```

[image: plot]